# Handle ASCII in R

Tags: r, ascii, file-handling

I have some files of Micro Data from a Populational Census stored as .txt and coded in ASCII.
When I open them in a text editor I get something like:
`1100015110001500100100003624008705865085282310200600101011022022  14 444231` etc.

Since I have no expirience with the tabulation of ASCII data I would like to know if there is any way to get this done with R and/or what type of suplementary software do I need.

Actually at first I would like to have a "normal" look at my data, as to say, to see it as a table if possible (the filesizes vary between 40mb and 500mb). Then I would like to make some simple calculations and store the results later as a csv. to use it in other contexts.

Can anyone give me some advice?

Comment: You provide insufficient context. In general R is able to handle such text data just fine, and ASCII is a supported encoding. You can specify a `fileEncoding` for functions such as `read.table` but you don’t need to in the first place if your data is only numeric.

Comment: point us to the data files you are looking at!  :)

Comment: the  main problem is, that the data appears in ASCII code. I don't know how to convert it to characters or how to use it in this form in R. here is a example for the data ftp://ftp.ibge.gov.br/Censos/Censo_Demografico_2010/Resultados_Gerais_da_Amostra/Microdados/AP.zip

Comment: @Joschi where is the page that you got this link from?  are there SAS import instructions anywhere?

Comment: If you mean that your source file is supposed to contain the 2- or 3- digit ASCII codes for the actual data, then you have to find out what the format (delimiters, e.g.) is of the source file. Neither R nor any other language can automagically do that for you.

Comment: if you have access to a linux box (or cygwin on windows) call `head |od -c` this will give you the first five lines of the file character by character. if you can find the file seperator (most likely `\s` or `\t` then you can pass this as an argument to `read.table` in R and get the data in.

Comment: another option for the brazilian censo demografico: http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/censo%20demografico%20no%20brasil%20%28censo%29

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this brazilian census website provides a SAS importation script.  the quickest way to import an ASCII data set with only a SAS importation script is to use [the SAScii package](http://cran.r-project.org/package=SAScii).  you can find the SAS importation script inside [this zipped file](ftp://ftp.ibge.gov.br/Trabalho_e_Rendimento/Pesquisa_Mensal_de_Emprego/Microdados/documentacao/Documentacao.zip) -- it's INPUT.txt.  notice that the INPUT block of those SAS importation instructions don't start until the fourth line, so your `beginline` parameter will be 4.  test out that you're reading the SAS script correctly first with `?parse.SAScii`

```
library(SAScii)
parse.SAScii( "INPUT.txt" , beginline = 4 )
```

once you see that that's printed the column names and widths correctly, you can use the `?read.SAScii` function to directly read your text file into an R data frame

```
x <- read.SAScii( "filename.txt" , "INPUT.txt" , beginline = 4 )
head( x )
```

if your file is too big to read entirely into RAM, you can instead read it into a SQLite database.  use the `read.SAScii.sqlite()` function found not in the SAScii package but in [my github account here](https://github.com/ajdamico/usgsd/blob/master/SQLite/read.SAScii.sqlite.R) -- it's just a slight variation of the read.SAScii() function, but it doesn't overload RAM.  you can see an example of its usage in the download script on this [united states government survey data set website](http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/area%20resource%20file%20%28arf%29).

for more detail about the SAScii package, check out [this overview](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2012/07/importing-public-data-with-sas-instructions-into-r.html)

Comment: in case you can't find the SAS importation script, even if there's a layout file, you could properly construct a `read.fwf` call as Romain stated above from importing the excel layout.  it has where fields begin and end, so you just have take the starting and ending positions, and use their difference as the `width` parameter  :)  good luck!

Comment: all right. Until know it works just fine with the SAS importation script ;)

Comment: ok just finished reading the smallest file with 78,344 observations of 187 variables. it took about 4:30 minutes. so maybe it is really good idea to work with a database!

Comment: @Joschi the SQLite route will actually be slower - try the largest file instead and see if it overloads your RAM  :)  one other options might be to use `parse.SAScii` just to determine the field widths, then use `fwf2csv` in the `descr` package.. at which point you can `read.csv` or `read.csv.sql` and still not overload RAM.  [there's an example of this being done in the middle of this function](https://github.com/ajdamico/usgsd/blob/master/MonetDB/read.SAScii.monetdb.R)

Comment: @Joschi idk if you can tell, i do this a lot ;)

Comment: ok i tried and it dind't crash. But it took a while ;) Thanks for indicating and developing this package i'll surely use it a lot for future analyses of Micro Data!!!

Answer (score 2):

A good alternative is the package `readr`, an [extremely fast solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24715894/faster-way-to-read-fixed-width-files-in-r) to read fixed column width data. More info on `readr` [here](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2015/04/new-packages-for-reading-data-into-r-fast.html).

So instead of `read.SAScii`, you can use a faster option based in `readr`. Like this:

```
# Load Packages
  library(readr)
  library(SAScii)
  library(data.table)


# Parse input file
  dic_pes2013 <- parse.SAScii("INPUT.txt")

  setDT(dic_pes2013) # convert to data.table

# read to data frame
  pesdata2 <- read_fwf("./Dados/PES2013.txt", 
                       fwf_widths(dput(dic_pes2013[,width]),
                                  col_names=(dput(dic_pes2013[,varname]))),
                                  progress = interactive()
                                  )
```

I've just read 2.4 million records with 243 variables in 1.2 minutes (file `Amostra_Pessoas_35_outras.txt`).

ps. if you don't have the `input.txt` files, [here](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/89417/arquivos-de-leitura-em-ascii-do-censo-demografico-2010/90437#90437) is short script on how to create them.

**Note that some variables have decimals**, something that is not incorporated in the solutions provided by the answers posted here (at least so far). To take this into account, I would recommend this `R` script [here](https://github.com/rafapereirabr/Brazilian_Census_2010) , which will help you download the 2010 Brazilian Census data sets, read them into data frames and save them as `.csv` files.