# Read a SAS data file into R based on a SAS script (NHANES III)

Tags: r, sas

I am attempting to read NHANES III, a publicly available epidemiological dataset available from:
https://wwwn.cdc.gov/nchs/nhanes/nhanes3/datafiles.aspx#core

It is not clear how to do this but they do provide a data file and a SAS file:

https://wwwn.cdc.gov/nchs/data/nhanes3/1a/lab.dat

https://wwwn.cdc.gov/nchs/data/nhanes3/1a/lab.sas

The data file does not seem to be a conventional SAS export format. Here is a sample of the header:

00003038722311121202610404037061400.6411144120   000001523001737.58001735.14003702.83                  000000000         000000000000003046003475.15003470.28007405.66                  000000000

But the SAS file seems to describe its format with LENGTH, FORMAT, INPUT and LABEL headers:

```
FILENAME LAB "D:\LAB\DAT\LAB.DAT" LRECL=1979;
*** LRECL includes 2 positions for CRLF, assuming use of PC SAS;

DATA WORK;
  INFILE LAB MISSOVER;


LENGTH
    SEQN      4
    DMPFSEQ   5
    DMPSTAT   3
    ......
 FORMAT
    DMPPIR   Z6.3
    WTPFQX6  Z9.2
    WTPFEX6  Z9.2
    ......
 INPUT
    SEQN     1-5
    DMPFSEQ  6-10
    DMPSTAT  11
    ......
LABEL
    SEQN     = "Sample person identification number"
    DMPFSEQ  = "Family sequence number"
    DMPSTAT  = "Examination/interview Status"
```

Any idea how to read this into a friendly format?

Comment: Do you know how the data should look like?

Comment: I think it should be a table of data with ~30k rows and ~356 columns. Column names are present in the LABEL section of the second file.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50298419/import-dat-file-from-repository-using-r)'s a similar question.

Comment: There are multiple packages to read in NHANES data: nhanes-A, RNHANES and others... unfortunately they cannot read this specific NHANES dataset, only the continuous NHANES from 1999 onwards.

Comment: Yes thank you I did not find that similar question but it proposes the same solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible using the `SAScii` package. It might take a couple of minutes though.

```
library(SAScii)
read.SAScii("https://wwwn.cdc.gov/nchs/data/nhanes3/1a/lab.dat", 
                      "https://wwwn.cdc.gov/nchs/data/nhanes3/1a/lab.sas", zipped = F)
```