# How to convert sas .matrix file to csv or tsv file?

Tags: r, sas

I have been given two sas files named x.matrix which contains data and x.info which contains columns information. Since I code in R, I would like to convert them tables to a standard tab/comma delimited files. I tried readr package as well as read.delim in R with no chance; column names in .info do not match the table in R. My guess is that .matrix has variable number of white spaces between the columns! I have partially pasted the content of each for clarification. I will be appreciative if some could help me out. The final goal, any way, is to read in the .matrix file in R. Any solution then is appreciated. Thanks. x.matrix and x.info respectively:
[x.matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCDvv.png) and
[x.info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Z4zZ.png)

Comment: Check out this solution https://stackoverflow.com/q/25925381/10276092

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: They are fixed space files. R has a read.fwf function. The second one has the information to read the first one. Anthony Damico’s work might make it easier.