# read.table with "right-aligned" data

Tags: r, read.table, data-import

I have a text file to read in R, but the file does not seem to be tab-delimited. The only structure of the file is that columns always finish at some point (i.e. columns are right aligned).

So, first, is there a name for this type of data structure? Then, how can read it in R?

```
    2.37      2.03                          2.38
   5,397     5,082                         5,609
    13.0      21.6          15.2            15.2
   128.0     103.1         134.2           133.4
```

Just using read.table() doesn't work, the missing value won't be put at the right place...

```
# download data:
tmp <- tempfile()
f <- download.file("http://usda.mannlib.cornell.edu/usda/waob/wasde//1990s/1995/wasde-01-12-1995.txt", tmp)
D <- file(tmp)
data_enc <- readLines(D, warn=FALSE)
close(D)
dat <- sapply(strsplit(data_enc[232:236], ":"), function(x) x[2])
writeLines(dat, tmp)

## try to read data:
read.table(tmp, fill = TRUE, sep ="", header=FALSE)
```

Gives:

```
      V1    V2    V3    V4
 1  2.37  2.03  2.38    NA
 2 5,397 5,082 5,609    NA
 3  13.0  21.6  15.2  15.2
```

Comment: Relevant post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24715894

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try using `read.fwf` to read a table of fixed width formatted data:

```
widths <- gregexpr("\\.\\d", readLines(tmp)[5])[[1]]+1L # line 5 looks complete
widths <- c(widths[1], diff(widths)) # posis after the decimal points as widths
read.fwf(tmp, widths = widths)
#         V1         V2    V3               V4
# 1     2.37       2.03    NA             2.38
# 2    5,397      5,082    NA            5,609
# 3     13.0       21.6  15.2             15.2
# 4    128.0      103.1 134.2            133.4
# 5    146.4      130.9 156.5            155.7
```

Comment: oh nice! So is this data still a fixed-width data? I was tricked by thinking that fixed width involved not only same end but also same start!? Then maybe Hadley's package readr will make it very easy: read_fwf(tmp, fwf_empty(tmp))

Comment: ... yep, even better. :-)