# Speeding Up Parsing Text to data.table in R

Tags: r, performance, parsing, data.table

I read a text file into R using `read.table()` resulting in a data frame with one column of unparsed data.

I also have a data dictionary that includes the column names and their beginning and end character position for each row of the text file.

This is my approach to parsing the text file with a small example:

```
library(data.table)

df <- data.frame(
  parse=c("123qweASD","234werSDF","345ertDFG"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

guide <- data.frame(
 name=c("c1","c2","c3"),
 begin=c(1,3,6),
 end=c(2,5,9)
)

emptyDF <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = nrow(guide), 
                             nrow = nrow(df)))
colnames(emptyDF) <- as.character(unlist(guide[1]))
emptyDF[is.na(emptyDF)] <- ""

setDT(emptyDF)

for(y in 1:nrow(df)){
  split <- character()
  for(z in 1:nrow(guide)){
    extr <- substr(df[y,], guide[z, 2], guide[z, 3])
    split <- c(split, extr)
  }
  emptyDF <- emptyDF[y, names(emptyDF) := as.list(split)]
}
```

resulting in this:

```
> emptyDF
   c1  c2   c3
1: 12 3qw eASD
2: 23 4we rSDF
3: 34 5er tDFG
```

To avoid appending and to speed things up I created an empty data.table the same row length as the unparsed data and replaced its rows with the parsed rows

The approach works but it takes a while to run with a file that has 200,000 rows and 90 columns.

Is there anything else I can be doing to speed this up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about `readr::read_fwf`? It is much faster and robust to errors.

Taking the big Dataset by Warner:

```
writeLines(as.character(unlist(df1[1])), con="df1.txt")
system.time({
  a4 <- read_fwf("df1.txt", fwf_widths(guide1$end+1-guide1$begin))
})

  user  system elapsed 
4.398    0.390   4.975

system.time({
  a2 <- read.fwf("df1.txt", guide1$end+1-guide1$begin)
})

   user  system elapsed 
101.583  83.111 190.462

system.time({
a3 <- setDT(setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame, 
                     Map(substring, df1$v1, list(guide1$begin), list(guide1$end))), guide1$names))[]
})

   user  system elapsed 
140.660   2.790 147.322
```

This last timing is screwed as it does not read the data from file. It reads it from memory. To really compare the timing you would also need to add the time of something like `readLines` to it.

Comment: does this have any advantages over the base-R function?

Comment: Accepted this answer because I have a lot of large data sets and this is really fast.

Answer (score 4):

if you know the beginning and end character position for each row of the text file you should definitely be using `?read.fwf` from base R (`fread` doesn't have any such capability, but you can convert it to a `data.table` afterwards ...)

```
writeLines(c("123qweASD","234werSDF","345ertDFG"),
            con="tmpfwf.txt")
guide <- data.frame(
    name=c("c1","c2","c3"),
    begin=c(1,3,6),
    end=c(2,5,9)
)

df <- read.fwf("tmpfwf.txt",guide$end+1-guide$begin)
data.table::data.table(df)
##    V1  V2   V3
## 1: 12 3qw eASD
## 2: 23 4we rSDF
## 3: 34 5er tDFG
```

Comment: `read.fwf` was _much_ faster. Thanks a lot!

Comment: maybe post timings, as a supplementary answer?  I didn't bother to construct a realistic sized example, but I think that would be useful information

Comment: I agree! Just posted them.

Comment: @Warner See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24715894/faster-way-to-read-fixed-width-files-in-r/34190156#34190156) for benchmarks on many fixed-width input options

Answer (score 2):

**Edit to include 3rd approach**

Providing a comparison of timings of my approach, @Ben Bolker's, and @akrun's. I don't usually compare speeds so there might be a more eloquent way of setting this up. Open to suggestions.

I created an example with 500 rows and one with 250,000 rows. I look at the time it takes to split into 10 columns and 100 columns.

**Approach 1:** Empty `data.table()` populated using for loop.

**Approach 2:** `read.fwf()`

**Approach 3:** `setDT()` with `substring`

Here is the **time these approaches take in minutes**:

```
> results
                   DataSize   Approach1   Approach2   Approach3
1      500 Rows, 10 Columns  0.01934705 0.002605216 0.001200851
2     500 rows, 100 Columns  0.07892265 0.028603617 0.014927268
3  250,000 Rows, 10 Columns  6.84735728 1.527935565 1.585325948
4 250,000 rows, 100 Columns 37.34443290 8.075678647 4.172232886
```

`read.fwf()` is clearly faster than the for loops I used in my approach. The `substring` approach is the fastest. Interestingly the three approaches scale differently depending on the the number columns vs rows:

```
> # Time factor increase with column and row increases
> scaling
                                     Increase  Approach1  Approach2   Approach3
1   500 Rows: Increase from 10 to 100 Columns   4.079311  10.979366   12.430577
2  250k Rows: Increase from 10 to 100 Columns   5.453846   5.285353    2.631782
3  10 Columns: Increase from 500 to 250k Rows 353.922518 586.490999 1320.168952
4 100 Columns: Increase from 500 to 250k Rows 473.177640 282.330677  279.504118
```

It appears that the empty `data.table` approach scales better than `read.fwf()` and the `substring` approach when there is either a small number of columns or a small number of rows. Any thoughts on why this is?

Another thought: My data set has a little less columns and rows than the biggest example here. But it took almost an hour to parse. Each row in my data set 700-800 characters and the resulting columns are of varying sizes. This is another dimension of performance and speed worth considering.

Here is how I set this up.

**Set up tables with random strings and guide tables**

```
library(stringi)

df1 <- data.frame(
  v1=stri_rand_strings(n=250000, length=200, pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]"),
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE
)
df2 <- as.data.frame(df1[1:500,])

guide1 <- data.frame(
  names=paste0(rep("c",100), 1:100),
  begin=(1:100)*2-1,
  end=(1:100)*2,
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

guide2 <- data.frame(
  names=paste0(rep("c",10), 1:10),
  begin=(0:9)*20+1,
  end=(1:10)*20,
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

**Set up the functions for both approaches**

```
approach1 <- function(emptydf, df, guide){
  for(y in 1:nrow(df)){
    split <- character()
    for(z in 1:nrow(guide)){
      extr <- substr(df[y,], guide[z, 2], guide[z, 3])
      split <- c(split, extr)
    }
    emptydf <- emptydf[y, names(emptydf) := as.list(split)]
  }
  return(emptydf)
}


approach2 <- function(path, guide){
  import <- read.fwf(path, guide$end+1-guide$begin)
}


approach3 <- function(df, guide){
      setDT(setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame, Map(substring, df$v1, 
                  list(guide$begin), list(guide$end))), guide$names))[] 

}
```

**Approach 1: Empty data.table with For loops:**

```
emptydf1 <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = nrow(guide1), 
                              nrow = nrow(df1)))
colnames(emptydf1) <- as.character(unlist(guide1[1]))
emptydf1[is.na(emptydf1)] <- ""

emptydf2 <- as.data.frame(emptydf1[, 1:10])
emptydf3 <- as.data.frame(emptydf1[1:500,])
emptydf4 <- as.data.frame(emptydf1[1:500,1:10])

setDT(emptydf1)
setDT(emptydf2)
setDT(emptydf3)
setDT(emptydf4)

## 500 rows and 10 columns
a0 <- Sys.time()
app1Out1 <- approach1(emptydf4, df2, guide2)
a1 <- Sys.time()
## 500 rows and 100 columns
b0 <- Sys.time()
app1Out2 <- approach1(emptydf3, df2, guide1)
b1 <- Sys.time()
## 250,000 rows and 10 columns
c0 <- Sys.time()
app1Out3 <- approach1(emptydf2, df1, guide2)
c1 <- Sys.time()
## 250,000 rows and 100 columns
d0 <- Sys.time()
app1Out4 <- approach1(emptydf1, df1, guide1)
d1 <- Sys.time()
```

**Approach 2:** `read.fwf()`

```
writeLines(as.character(unlist(df1[1])), con="df1.txt")
writeLines(as.character(unlist(df2[1])), con="df2.txt")

## 500 rows and 10 columns
e0 <- Sys.time()
app2Out1 <- approach2("df2.txt", guide2)
e1 <- Sys.time()
## 500  rows and 100 columns
f0 <- Sys.time()
app2Out2 <- approach2("df2.txt", guide1)
f1 <- Sys.time()
## 500 rows and 10 columns
g0 <- Sys.time()
app2Out3 <- approach2("df1.txt", guide2)
g1 <- Sys.time()
## 250,00 rows and 100 columns
h0 <- Sys.time()
app2Out4 <- approach2("df1.txt", guide1)
h1 <- Sys.time()
```

**Approach 3:** `setDF()` with `substring`

```
names(df2) <- "v1"

## 500 rows and 10 columns
i0 <- Sys.time()
app3Out1 <- approach3(df2, guide2)
i1 <- Sys.time()
## 500 rows and 100 columns
j0 <- Sys.time()
app3Out2 <- approach3(df2, guide1)
j1 <- Sys.time()
## 250,000 rows and 10 columns
k0 <- Sys.time()
app3Out3 <- approach3(df1, guide2)
k1 <- Sys.time()
## 250,000 rows and 100 columns
l0 <- Sys.time()
app3Out4 <- approach3(df1, guide1)
l1 <- Sys.time()
```

**Set result tables up**

```
tests <- c("500 Rows, 10 Columns","500 rows, 100 Columns","250,000 Rows, 10 Columns",
           "250,000 rows, 100 Columns")
app1 <- c(as.numeric(a1-a0)/60,as.numeric(b1-b0)/60,as.numeric(c1-c0),as.numeric(d1-d0))
app2 <- c(as.numeric(e1-e0)/60,as.numeric(f1-f0)/60,as.numeric(g1-g0),as.numeric(h1-h0))
app3 <- c(as.numeric(i1-i0)/60,as.numeric(j1-j0)/60,as.numeric(k1-k0),as.numeric(l1-l0))

results <- data.frame(
  "DataSize"=tests,
  "Approach1"=app1,
  "Approach2"=app2,
  "Approach3"=app3
)

# Time factor with increase with column and row increases
scaling <- data.frame(
  "Increase"=c("500 Rows: Increase from 10 to 100 Columns","250k Rows: Increase from 10 to 100 Columns",
               "10 Columns: Increase from 500 to 250k Rows","100 Columns: Increase from 500 to 250k Rows"),
  "Approach1"=c((results[2,2]/results[1,2]),(results[4,2]/results[3,2]),
                (results[3,2]/results[1,2]),(results[4,2]/results[2,2])),
  "Approach2"=c((results[2,3]/results[1,3]),(results[4,3]/results[3,3]),
                (results[3,3]/results[1,3]),(results[4,3]/results[2,3])),
  "Approach3"=c((results[2,4]/results[1,4]),(results[4,4]/results[3,4]),
                (results[3,4]/results[1,4]),(results[4,4]/results[2,4]))
  )
```

Comment: In the last case, where are the `results`?

Comment: Just added your approach.

Comment: It's awesome you took the time to do this. The `mircrobenchmark` package might help you out in the future.

Comment: Could you please add `readr::read_fwf` in your benchmark (see my answer)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option with `substring`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame, Map(substring, df$parse, 
         list(guide$begin), list(guide$end))), guide$name))[] 
#   c1  c2   c3
#1: 12 3qw eASD
#2: 23 4we rSDF
#3: 34 5er tDFG
```

Comment: This works too - I will have to include this in the performance and speed comparisons.