# Convert string dataset to a matrix

Tags: r, string, split, bioinformatics

I have a dataset separated by tab, so I would want to convert the following dataset into a matrix

```
CATGGGGAAAACTGA
CCTCTCGATCACCGA
CCTATAGATCACCGA
CCGATTGATCACCGA
CCTTGTGCAGACCGA
```

I used to use

```
rbind(strsplit("CATGGGGAAAACTGA","")[[1]],
        strsplit("CCTCTCGATCACCGA","")[[1]],
        strsplit("CCTCTCGATCACCGA","")[[1]],
        strsplit("CCTATAGATCACCGA","")[[1]],
        strsplit("CCGATTGATCACCGA","")[[1]],
        strsplit("CCTTGTGCAGACCGA","")[[1]])
```

And this produces:

```
[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15]
[1,] "C"  "A"  "T"  "G"  "G"  "G"  "G"  "A"  "A"  "A"   "A"   "C"   "T"   "G"   "A"  
[2,] "C"  "C"  "T"  "C"  "T"  "C"  "G"  "A"  "T"  "C"   "A"   "C"   "C"   "G"   "A"  
[3,] "C"  "C"  "T"  "C"  "T"  "C"  "G"  "A"  "T"  "C"   "A"   "C"   "C"   "G"   "A"  
[4,] "C"  "C"  "T"  "A"  "T"  "A"  "G"  "A"  "T"  "C"   "A"   "C"   "C"   "G"   "A"  
[5,] "C"  "C"  "G"  "A"  "T"  "T"  "G"  "A"  "T"  "C"   "A"   "C"   "C"   "G"   "A"  
[6,] "C"  "C"  "T"  "T"  "G"  "T"  "G"  "C"  "A"  "G"   "A"   "C"   "C"   "G"   "A"
```

But when the dataset is very large, this process is exhausting. How could I do it automatically?

Comment: use `do.call`: something like `do.call("rbind", lapply(myDNAVec, strsplit, split=""))`.

Comment: Is the sequence lengths fixed, always 15?

Comment: @lmo No need for `lapply`. `strsplit(myDNAvec, split = '')` will work.

Comment: _Possibly_ relevant Q&A: [Faster way to read fixed-width files in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24715894/faster-way-to-read-fixed-width-files-in-r)

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks. `lapply` creates a needless nest and probably additional overhead. `do.call(rbind, strsplit(myDNAvec, split = ''))` is better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `read.fwf` to split into single characters:

```
read.fwf(textConnection("CATGGGGAAAACTGA
CCTCTCGATCACCGA
CCTATAGATCACCGA
CCGATTGATCACCGA
CCTTGTGCAGACCGA"), rep(1, nchar("CATGGGGAAAACTGA")))
#  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15
#1  C  A  T  G  G  G  G  A  A   A   A   C   T   G   A
#2  C  C  T  C  T  C  G  A  T   C   A   C   C   G   A
#3  C  C  T  A  T  A  G  A  T   C   A   C   C   G   A
#4  C  C  G  A  T  T  G  A  T   C   A   C   C   G   A
#5  C  C  T  T  G  T  G  C  A   G   A   C   C   G   A
```

You might want to pass a file name instead of a text connection.