# Processing without entirely loading a table

Tags: r, database, c++11

I have a file of approximately 40Gb and i need to perform some analytics activity on it but my ram is limited to 4gb any suggestions how to proceed?

Comment: I've voted to close this answer because it is too broad. You will get a better answer if you show what you have tried to do and why it didn't work.

Comment: What kind of analytics are you trying to do? Maybe you could process it in chunks?

Comment: see the "Large Memory and Out-of-Memory Data" section of the [High-Performance Computing Task View](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the LaF package. It allows you to do column selection and filtering on files that would not otherwise fit into memory.

Documentation and examples are a little thin on the ground which is a shame given that the syntax is a little idiosyncratic. This may help:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24716798/1427069

Answer (score 0):

Increase Your Virtual Memory:
increase the size of the paging file