# Manipulating character arrays quickly in R data.table

Tags: arrays, r, data.table

I have a huge datatset (14GB, 200 Mn rows) of character vector. I've fread it (took > 30 mins on 48 core 128 GB server). The string contains **concatenated** information on various fields. For instance, the first row of my table looks like:

```
2014120900000001091500bbbbcompany_name00032401
```

where the first 8 characters represent `date` in YYYYMMDD format, next 8 characters are `id`, next 6 the `time` in HHMMSS format and then next 16 are `name` (prefixed with b's) and the last 8 are `price` (2 decimal places).

I need to transfer the above 1 column data.table into 5 columns: `date, id, time, name, price`.

For the above character vector that will  turn out to be: `date = "2014-12-09", id = 1, time = "09:15:00", name = "company_name", price = 324.01`

I am looking for a (very) fast and efficient dplyr / data.table solution. Right now I am doing it with using `substr`:

```
date = as.Date(substr(d, 1, 8), "%Y%m%d");
```

and it's taking forever to execute!

> *Update*: With `readr::read_fwf` I am able to read the file in 5-10 mins. Apparently, the reading is faster than `fread`. Below is the code:

```
f = "file_name";
num_cols = 5;
col_widths = c(8,8,6,16,8);
col_classes = "ciccn";
col_names = c("date", "id", "time", "name", "price");

# takes 5-10 mins
data = readr::read_fwf(file = f, col_positions = readr::fwf_widths(col_widths, col_names), col_types = col_classes, progress = T);

setDT(data);
# object.size(data) / 2^30; # 17.5 GB
```

Comment: Did you try read.fwf to directly read the fixed substrings into different columns?

Comment: Related: [Faster way to read fixed-width files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24715894/faster-way-to-read-fixed-width-files)

Comment: @Henrik thanks for pointing out. I didn't know about fixed width reading (which is precisely what I wanted).

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

```
library(data.table)
library(stringi)

widths <- c(8,8,6,16,8)
sp <- c(1, cumsum(widths[-length(widths)]) + 1)
ep <- cumsum(widths)

DT[, lapply(seq_along(sp), function(i) stri_sub(V1, sp[i], ep[i]))]
```

which gives:

> ```
>          V1       V2     V3               V4       V5
> 1: 20141209 00000001 091500 bbbbcompany_name 00032401
> ```

Including some additional processing to get the desired result:

```
DT[, lapply(seq_along(sp), function(i) stri_sub(V1, sp[i], ep[i]))
   ][, .(date = as.Date(V1, "%Y%m%d"),
         id = as.integer(V2),
         time = as.ITime(V3, "%H%M%S"),
         name = sub("^(bbbb)","",V4),
         price = as.numeric(V5)/100)]
```

which gives:

> ```
>          date id     time         name  price
> 1: 2014-12-09  1 09:15:00 company_name 324.01
> ```

---

But you are actually reading a fixed width file. So could also consider `read.fwf` from base R or `read_fwf`from [readr](/questions/tagged/readr) or write your own `fread.fwf`-function like I did a while ago:

```
fread.fwf <- function(file, widths, enc = "UTF-8") {
  sp <- c(1, cumsum(widths[-length(widths)]) + 1)
  ep <- cumsum(widths)
  fread(file = file, header = FALSE, sep = "\n", encoding = enc)[, lapply(seq_along(sp), function(i) stri_sub(V1, sp[i], ep[i]))]
}
```

---

Used data:

```
DT <- data.table(V1 = "2014120900000001091500bbbbcompany_name00032401")
```

Comment: Thans @Jaap for the solution. I have tried with `readr::read_fwf` which gives me a satisfactory performance. I am yet to try your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your solution is not so bad.

I am using this data:

```
df <- data.table(text = rep("2014120900000001091500bbbbcompany_name00032401", 100000))
```

**Your solution:**

```
> system.time(df[, .(date = as.Date(substr(text, 1, 8), "%Y%m%d"),
+                    id = as.integer(substr(text, 9, 16)),
+                    time = substr(text, 17, 22),
+                    name = substr(text, 23, 38),
+                    price = as.numeric(substr(text, 39, 46))/100)])
   user  system elapsed 
   0.17    0.00    0.17
```

**@Jaap solution:**

```
> library(data.table)
> library(stringi)
> 
> widths <- c(8,8,6,16,8)
> sp <- c(1, cumsum(widths[-length(widths)]) + 1)
> ep <- cumsum(widths)
> 
> system.time(df[, lapply(seq_along(sp), function(i) stri_sub(text, sp[i], ep[i]))
+    ][, .(date = as.Date(V1, "%Y%m%d"),
+          id = as.integer(V2),
+          time = V3,
+          name = sub("^(bbbb)","",V4),
+          price = as.numeric(V5)/100)])
   user  system elapsed 
   0.20    0.00    0.21
```

**An attempt with read.fwf:**

```
> setClass("myDate")
> setAs("character","myDate", function(from) as.Date(from, format = "%Y%m%d"))
> setClass("myNumeric")
> setAs("character","myNumeric", function(from) as.numeric(from)/100)
> 
> ff <- function(x) {
+   file <- textConnection(x)
+   read.fwf(file, c(8, 8, 6, 16, 8),
+            col.names = c("date", "id", "time", "name", "price"),
+            colClasses = c("myDate", "integer", "character", "character", "myNumeric"))
+ }
> 
> system.time(df[, as.list(ff(text))])
   user  system elapsed 
   2.33    6.15    8.49
```

All outputs are the same.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try using matrix with numeric instead of data.frame. Aggregation should take less time.