# extract several variables from string position using a dictionary (varname,startposition,endposition) in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, lapply, fixed-width

I have a data.table, `DT` containing one string variable, `s`, from which I want to create additional variables based on the positions of each character in `s`. The `varname`, `start` and `end` positions and `vartype` of each variable are given in a dictionary, `dic`. Here is an example, including the desired output:

```
DT <- DT <- data.table(s=c('a191','b292','c393'))
dic <- data.table(varname=c('bla,ble,bli'),start=c(1,2,3),end=c(1,2,4),vartype=c('c','i','i')
DTdesired <- data.table(bla=c('a','b','c'),ble=c(1,2,3),bli=c(91,92,93))
```

This is the same problem as importing data from a fixed width file (fwf), [which has been covered in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24715894/faster-way-to-read-fixed-width-files). The answer to that post includes a data table solution

```
 DT[ , lapply(seq_len(length(cols$beg)), function(ii) {
      stri_sub(V1, cols$beg[ii], cols$end[ii])
    })]
```

But I am looking for a solution that besides `start` and `end` would also use the `varname` and `coltype` variables of the dictionary

Edit: In reality, `DT` would be a large Census file, around 200 million observations. Each element of `s` is a string with 200 characters. And the dictionary, `dic`, can contain about 10 to 50 variables to be extracted, depending on the year.

Comment: Try `type.convert(dic[, setNames(Map(function(x, y) substr(DT$s, x, y), star, end), strsplit(varname[1], ",")[[1]])][, s := DT$s][], as.is = TRUE)`

Comment: @akrun, as always, tks! This looks like black magic to me. But it works. In case you want to submit this as an answer, for clarity I fixed a typo in the original post (start not star), and removed column s from the output file. Do you expect that this be memory efficient and fast? I have a dataset with 200mm obs, extracting 12 columns. The server I used has been stuck executing read_fwf for 24hs....

Comment: You meant `200 million` observations?.  This code is actually looped by row of the 'dic' data.  So may not be that efficient

Comment: The dictionary has only 15 rows, corresponding to the 15 variables to be extracted. But DT has 200 million observations.

Comment: it could also increase efficiency if `type.convert()` could run within each iteration of the loop. Optimize each column at the time, instead of at the end

Comment: @akrun, this works quite well! I edited a bit. `subtr_typeconvert <- function(x, y) DT$s %>% substr(x, y) %>% type.convert(as.is = TRUE)`. Then loop: `DTdesired <- dic[, setNames(Map(function(x, y) subtr_typeconvert(x,y), start, end), varname)]`. Please add as answer so I can solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `Map` to do the conversion. (added the updated function created by @LucasMation)

```
library(magrittr)
library(data.table)
subtr_typeconvert <- function(x, y)
     {
 DT$s %>%
   substr(x, y) %>%
     type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
}
dic[, setNames(Map(function(x, y)
      subtr_typeconvert(x,y), start, end), varname)]
```