# Splitting concatenated data in large dataset. Looking for improvements in computation time

Tags: r, concatenation, large-data

I am working with a large dataframe that contains a concatenated vector with several pieces of information contained within that variable. I need to extract these values for my analysis, which could be done with the substr() function, but the observations are of varying length, making this unideal. While I have some working code, the size of my dataset means it takes quite a while to process and was wondering if there is maybe a better way.

For example, an 8-digit data point of "97110770"
contains the information

- time: 97, person: 11077, place: 0

But some values are 9-digits like "114123411"
which would have:

- time: 114, person:12341, place: 1

In order to remedy this, I thought to add a "0" to the front of smaller variables so they would all be the same length (the digits after time value is consistent, so it works properly) and came up with this code:

(Dataframe: `data`, Vector of interest: `speakerid`)

```
congv <- vector(mode = "numeric")
memberidv <- vector(mode = "numeric")
chamberv <- vector(mode = "numeric")

for (i in 1:length(data$speakerid)) {
  if(nchar(data$speakerid[i]) == 8) {
    data$speakerid[i] = paste0("0", data$speakerid[i])
  }
  
  congv <- append(congv, substr(data$speakerid[i], 1, 3) )
  memberidv <- append(memberidv, substr(data$speakerid[i], 4, 8))
  chamberv <- append(chamberv, substr(data$speakerid[i], 9, 9))
}

data <- cbind(data, cong = congv, memberid = memberidv, chamber = chamberv)
data <- select(data, "memberid", "count", "chamber", "cong")

rm(list = c("congv", "memberidv", "chamberv"))
```

This works, *but* due to the size of the data (over 100k observations) it takes a lot longer than I would like (as I might need to include more data later) and I'm wondering if there's a more efficient method of doing this (maybe not using a for-if loop?)

If not, I'm fairly new to R and would appreciate any other tips you may have about my code, thanks!

```
Example dataframe:

speakerid = c(97110770, 114123411, 93123770, 112123410, 93123770)
count = c(12, 3, 4, 0, 4)
data = data.frame(speakerid, count)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an alternative that doesn't use any strings at all

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, {congv=speakerid %/% 1e6; .(memberid=(speakerid-congv*1e6)%/%10, count, chamberv=speakerid %% 10, congv)}]
```

Output

```
   memberid count chamberv congv
      <num> <num>    <num> <num>
1:    11077    12        0    97
2:    12341     3        1   114
3:    12377     4        0    93
4:    12341     0        0   112
5:    12377     4        0    93
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `mapply` and use `sprintf` to add leading zeroes.

```
> cbind(data, `colnames<-`(mapply(substr, list(sprintf('%09d', data$speakerid)), 
+                                 c(1, 4, 9), c(3, 8, 9)),
+                          c('cong', 'memberid', 'chamber')))
  speakerid count cong memberid chamber
1  97110770    12  097    11077       0
2 114123411     3  114    12341       1
3  93123770     4  093    12377       0
4 112123410     0  112    12341       0
5  93123770     4  093    12377       0
----
```

*Data:*

```
> dput(data)
structure(list(speakerid = c("097110770", "114123411", "093123770", 
"112123410", "093123770"), count = c(12, 3, 4, 0, 4)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `tidyverse` option which adds the leading zeros, breaks up the strings and creates new columns in just a couple of lines, with no loops or intermediate variables:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  mutate(sid = ifelse(speakerid < 1e8, paste0('0', speakerid), speakerid)) %>%
  separate(sid, sep = c(4, 8), into = c('time', 'person', 'place'))
#>   speakerid count time person place
#> 1  97110770    12  097  11077     0
#> 2 114123411     3  114  12341     1
#> 3  93123770     4  093  12377     0
#> 4 112123410     0  112  12341     0
#> 5  93123770     4  093  12377     0
```

Comment: Tried this answer first because I generally like tidyverse, but I was having problems with the separate function. It was weirdly ignoring the leading zero and couldn't figure out why.

Answer (score 2):

**Use `read.fwf`**

```
start <- c(1, 4, 9)
end <- c(3, 8, 9)
clnames <- c('cong', 'memberid', 'chamber')

read.fwf(textConnection(sprintf("%09d", data$speakerid)), 
          end - start + 1, colClasses = "character", 
          col.names = clnames)

  cong memberid chamber
1  097    11077       0
2  114    12341       1
3  093    12377       0
4  112    12341       0
5  093    12377       0
```

**Use `substring`**

```
n <- length(start)
string <- formatC(data$speakerid, digits = 8, flag = '0', format = 'd') # use sprintf("%09d", data$speakerid)
res <- matrix(substring(rep(string, each = n), start, end), ncol = n, byrow = TRUE)
data[clnames] <- res
data

  speakerid count cong memberid chamber
1  97110770    12  097    11077       0
2 114123411     3  114    12341       1
3  93123770     4  093    12377       0
4 112123410     0  112    12341       0
5  93123770     4  093    12377       0
```

Comment: If the data is very huge, consider looking for a faster way of reading fixed width files https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24715894/faster-way-to-read-fixed-width-files

Answer (score 1):

I think we are all curious about a benchmark, so here's one ...or actually a bunch of them.

### TLDR

@langtang's numeric approach is the fastest but can be made even faster when base R data frames are used instead of `data.table` and when integers are used instead of doubles.

```r
data$speakerid <- as.integer(data$speakerid)
data$congv <- data$speakerid %/% 1e6L
data$memberid <- (data$speakerid - data$congv * 1e6L) %/% 10L
data$chamberv = data$speakerid %% 10L
```

#### Detailed comparison

I am not very familiar `data.table` and how expensive it is to create one from a data frame so I tried two versions of @langtang's answer. `langtang()` copies the data and sets up the `data.table` while `langtang2()` works with a pre-created `data.table`. I also created a base R version of this approach, `langtang.base()` and an integer-based version of it (`langtang.int()`) as well. And I was kind of missing regular expressions here, so that's what `regexp()` uses.

```r
langtang <- function(data) {
  data.dt <- copy(data)
  setDT(data.dt)[, {congv=speakerid %/% 1e6; .(memberid=(speakerid-congv*1e6)%/%10, 
                                               count, 
                                               chamberv=speakerid %% 10, congv)}]
}

langtang2 <- function(data) {
  data[, {congv=speakerid %/% 1e6; .(memberid=(speakerid-congv*1e6)%/%10, 
                                     count, 
                                     chamberv=speakerid %% 10, congv)}]
}

langtang.base <- function(data) {
  data$congv <- data$speakerid %/% 1e6
  data$memberid <- (data$speakerid - data$congv*1e6) %/% 10
  data$chamberv = data$speakerid %% 10
  data
}

langtang.int <- function(data) {
  data$congv <- data$speakerid %/% 1e6L
  data$memberid <- (data$speakerid - data$congv * 1e6L) %/% 10L
  data$chamberv = data$speakerid %% 10L
  data
}

regexp <- function(data) {
  new <- str_match(data$speakerid, '(.+)(.{5})(.)$')[, -1]
  colnames(new) <- c('time', 'person', 'place')
  cbind(data, new)
}

jay.sf <- function(data) {
  cbind(data, `colnames<-`(mapply(substr, list(sprintf('%09d', data$speakerid)), 
                               c(1, 4, 9), c(3, 8, 9)),
                        c('cong', 'memberid', 'chamber')))
}

onyambu.fwf <- function(data) {
  start <- c(1, 4, 9)
  end <- c(3, 8, 9)
  clnames <- c('cong', 'memberid', 'chamber')
  
  read.fwf(textConnection(sprintf("%09d", data$speakerid)), 
           end - start + 1, colClasses = "character", 
           col.names = clnames)
}

onyambu.substring <- function(data) {
  start <- c(1, 4, 9)
  end <- c(3, 8, 9)
  clnames <- c('cong', 'memberid', 'chamber')
  n <- length(start)
  string <- formatC(data$speakerid, digits = 8, flag = '0', format = 'd') # use sprintf("%09d", data$speakerid)
  res <- matrix(substring(rep(string, each = n), start, end), ncol = n, byrow = TRUE)
  data[clnames] <- res
  data
}

allan <- function(data) {
  data %>%
    mutate(sid = ifelse(speakerid < 1e8, paste0('0', speakerid), speakerid)) %>%
    separate(sid, sep = c(4, 8), into = c('time', 'person', 'place'))
}
```

I ran three runs of benchmarks with increasing data size (*n* = 1250, 12500, 125000), always eliminating the weakest contestants from the previous round.

```r
# basic setup
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)

speakerid = c(97110770, 114123411, 93123770, 112123410, 93123770)
count = c(12, 3, 4, 0, 4)
```

#### Round 1

*n* = 1250

```
n <- 250
data <- data.frame(speakerid=rep(speakerid, n), 
                   count=rep(count, n))
data.dt <- copy(data)
setDT(data.dt)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(langtang(data),
                               langtang2(data.dt),
                               langtang.base(data),
                               regexp(data),
                               jay.sf(data),
                               onyambu.fwf(data),
                               onyambu.substring(data),
                               allan(data))
# Unit: microseconds
#                    expr      min        lq       mean    median        uq      max neval cld
#          langtang(data)    976.1   1161.35   1331.288   1244.55   1373.10   2939.8   100  a 
#      langtang2(data.dt)    811.0    985.35   1190.367   1062.20   1337.90   2310.2   100  a 
#     langtang.base(data)     89.2    113.20    135.245    121.30    136.05    333.7   100  a 
#            regexp(data)   3049.2   3286.45   3946.237   3661.10   4236.55   9525.5   100  a 
#            jay.sf(data)   1103.6   1208.50   1411.578   1268.20   1530.65   3348.4   100  a 
#       onyambu.fwf(data) 137789.3 144659.35 160136.978 148346.20 158928.25 589380.2   100   b
# onyambu.substring(data)   1326.0   1429.55   1686.699   1576.25   1777.35   3765.3   100  a 
#             allan(data)   5994.4   6569.90   7215.019   6942.65   7452.50  18441.9   100  a
```

The `read.fwf` approach is clearly quite slow.

#### Round 2

*n* = 12500

```
n <- 2500
data <- data.frame(speakerid=rep(speakerid, n), 
                   count=rep(count, n))
data.dt <- copy(data)
setDT(data.dt)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(langtang(data),
                               langtang2(data.dt),
                               langtang.base(data),
                               regexp(data),
                               jay.sf(data),
                               # onyambu.fwf(data),
                               onyambu.substring(data),
                               allan(data))
# Unit: microseconds
#                    expr     min      lq      mean   median       uq     max neval    cld
#          langtang(data)  1785.6  2119.3  2671.620  2576.95  2882.20  4866.7   100  b    
#      langtang2(data.dt)  1617.1  1853.6  2465.617  2259.75  2606.25 15087.1   100  b    
#     langtang.base(data)   695.6   759.7   919.072   864.15   987.75  2091.2   100 a     
#            regexp(data) 30896.3 33057.8 35566.693 34371.90 36153.60 73589.2   100     e 
#            jay.sf(data)  9558.4 10635.2 12087.027 11363.95 12043.95 25411.6   100   c   
# onyambu.substring(data) 11565.6 12823.6 15322.647 14392.90 15199.25 38022.6   100    d  
#             allan(data) 37854.2 40268.1 42862.539 41142.40 43361.95 81044.0   100      f
```

Numeric approaches are clearly faster than everything else.

#### Round 3

*n* = 125000

```r
n <- 25000
data <- data.frame(speakerid=rep(speakerid, n), 
                   count=rep(count, n))
data.dt <- copy(data)
setDT(data.dt)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(langtang(data),
                               langtang2(data.dt),
                               langtang.base(data))
                               # regexp(data),
                               # jay.sf(data),
                               # onyambu.fwf(data),
                               # onyambu.substring(data),
                               # allan(data))
# Unit: milliseconds
#                expr    min       lq      mean   median       uq     max neval cld
#      langtang(data) 9.5165 10.33125 15.201069 11.92520 18.21255 33.3532   100   b
#  langtang2(data.dt) 8.9184 10.21545 13.917598 12.39715 15.96175 31.7269   100   b
# langtang.base(data) 6.8799  7.59580  9.476838  8.61200  9.73975 22.2968   100  a
```

`data.table` appears to be somewhat slower than base R. And here is when I started thinking about integers, so here comes...

#### Bonus round

```r
# using data from Round 3
data.int <- data
data.int$speakerid <- as.integer(data.int$speakerid)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(langtang.base(data),
                               langtang.int(data.int))
# Unit: milliseconds
#                   expr    min     lq     mean  median       uq     max neval cld
#    langtang.base(data) 6.8217 7.5668 9.481636 9.12455 10.02510 27.0047   100   b
# langtang.int(data.int) 2.5945 2.9901 3.819205 3.60780  3.99565 20.0268   100  a
```

Clearly, using integers instead of doubles brings another speedup.