# Reading ASCII data in R

Tags: r, ascii, extended-ascii, raw

I previously asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76113598/opening-raw-with-data-in-r?noredirect=1#comment134234502_76113598) about reading `.RAW` files in `R`. I have looked for more details on these files and have found this documentation:

[image: Data description 1]

And this:

[image: Data description 2]

I do not have experience with ASCII files but I have managed to open it using this code:

```
> l<-read.fwf("D://Data//1987//f990.87.raw",2189)
> head(l)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             V1
1     SUNRISE BLUFF ESTATES INC          810365125094900510144783298712MT5944203NN0000NNN81036512512N        5629           0           0        5629      230808           0        2930           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0      102250      109612       -7362           0      232005      185585       55795           0           0      241380       -9375      -16627           0      -26002           0           0           0           0           0           0           0       44728       24331       20397           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0        3792        2076        1716           0           0        4300           0        4300           0           0           0           0           0        2054        1590         464           0        1022           0        1022           0         213           0         213           0       21250       21250           0           0        7470        7360         110           0           0           0           0           0        1574           0        1574           0           0           0           0           0       92244       92244           0           0       36653       36653           0           0       26080          81       25999           0      241380      185585       55795           0           0           0      230808           0       28357       53875          58           0           0           0           0        9558        7074        6989           0           0           0           0     1118796           0     1232548     1215149       13709           0        2222           0     1225220           0     1249175     1241151      -16627      -26002     1215149           0        8747       36850           0           0      327206     1364564        2635       10253         407        1186           0           0           0           0           0           0      338995     1412853       11789       48289        3390C   1692 22705 13.4220    18-OCT-89870
2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          <NA>
3     NORTHEAST MISSOURI LIBRARY SERVICE 436017950094900230016683198712MO6344503NN0000NNN43601795012N           0        4793      161881      166675         539           0        6298           0        2116           0        2116           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0      175630      169751           0           0           0      169751        5878       77129        1645       84653           0           0           0       12357       12357           0           0       79241       79241           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0        6529        6529           0           0           0         250         250           0           0           0           0           0           0        2737        2737           0           0        1817        1817           0           0        1158        1158           0           0       29312       29312           0           0        2043        2043           0           0           0           0           0           0        1958        1958           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0       32342       32342           0           0      169744      169744           0           0           0           0         539           0         105       64811           0           0           0           0           0           0           0        2476           0           0           0           0       17260           0       77129       84653           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0       77129       84653       84653           0        1435        4557           0           0        1359        4819        6298       32143           0           0      161881      577828           0           0           0           0      170975      619348      169615      614528        1709C   1549 85294 55.069     18-OCT-89870
4                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          <NA>
```

Is there any easy way to structure this file? I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13972024/handle-ascii-in-r) but that uses `library(SAScii)` but it seems to be too specialized to a particular case.

If you want to try, the data is avaialable [here](https://data.nber.org/exempt-orgs/1987/).

Comment: You can try to read it as a .csv, have you tried that? [This answer could be helpful to you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17150216/1389394)

Comment: To read these files into a tabular format, you would use the `Char. length` column as the second argument of `read.fwf` (i.e. you need to pass the vector `c(4, 35, 9, 14, etc)` as the `widths` argument of `read.fwf`). There are over 200 of these and you will probably need to copy them by hand. However, once you do this, you can read as many records as you like into a data frame.