# Trouble with read.fwf

Tags: r, dataframe, ascii

I had previously asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76120329/reading-ascii-data-in-r?noredirect=1#comment134243164_76120329) about how to open ASCII files in R. Someone suggested that I could extract the character length from the master file and use `read.fwf`. I went ahead and digitalized the master file into a .csv, I then proceed to attempt to read my `.RAW` file but I am getting an error.

This is my code:

```
d86<-read.csv("path//86_MasterFile.csv")
d86$char<-as.numeric(as.vector(d86$X4))
t<-read.fwf("path/f990.86.raw",widths=d86$char)
```

This yields the error:

```
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 91 did not have 755 elements
```

Such error persists is I instead redefine NAs: `d86[is.na(d86)] <- 0`. This is what my character vector looks like:

```
> print(d86$char)
  [1]  4 35  9 14  2  1  2  2  2  5  2  1  1  4  1  1  1  9  2  1 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12
 [39] 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12
 [77] 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12
[115] 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12
[153] 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12  0 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12
[191] 12  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  6  6  6  0  3  3  9  2 10  0  0  0  0
[229]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
[267]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
[305]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
[343]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
[381]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
[419]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
[457]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
[495]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
[533]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
[571]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
[609]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
[647]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
[685]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
[723]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

And my csv file looks like:

```
> head(d86)
    V1   V2                        V3 V4 V5 V6  V7 V8 char
1 ï»¿1 E001       SampleCode63Number1  1  4  N   G       4
2    2 E002        NameofOrganization  5 35  A   E      35
3    3 E003 EmployeeIdentificationNo. 40  9  N E,F       9
4    4 E004     DocumentLocatorNumber 49 14  N   F      14
5    5 E005              SampleCode63 63  2  N   G       2
6    6 E006              RejectCode65 65  1  N   G       1
```

**Additional info:**

The data is available [here](https://data.nber.org/exempt-orgs/1986/). Indeed, the problem seems to be line 91, but there is nothing particularly different about it in the source, nor data. See:

[image: Line from the pdf file]

```
d86[91,]
   V1   V2                  V3  V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 char
91 91 E091 Supplies-ColumnC940 940 12            12
```

This is how the `.RAW` file looks like:

```
  HEIGHTS COMMUNITY CONGRESS         237242552174900020040583198705OH4411803NN    NNN23724255211N       59101           0       11250       70351           0           0        3616           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0      147269           0      147269           0           0           0           0      221236      151518       34814       18916           0      205248       15988       22190           0       38178           0           0           0           0           0           0           0      117398       83971       23924        9503        1524         983         348         193           0           0           0           0        6325        4170        1574         581           0        1000         650         350           0           0           0           0           0       37683       32703         940        4040        3951        2309        1576          66        5980        4071         540        1369        5382        3146        2236           0        2529        1745         605         179        3401        2528         340         533        1729        1593          29         107        9215        8195         281         739           0           0           0           0        2315        1158         877         280        6816        4296        1194        1326      205248      151518       34814       18916           0           0           0           0         744           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0       43108       56969        2071           0           0        3248       86982       63032        3854           0           0           0           0       21000       64792       24854       22190       38178       63032           0      111631      362894           0           0       49930      185705        3739       16728           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0      165300      565327      115370      379622        1653C    547 30053 54.9441    06-DEC-88861788040201

    COLUMBUS JEWISH HOME/AGED-HERITAGE 314417962174900023850183498706OH4320903NN    NNY31441796211N     2299106           0           0     2299106     3728572           0      301315           0           0           0           0           0       13226           0       13226         200           0         200       13426           0           0           0           0           0           0           0     6342419     2953412     1262136       25534           0     4241082     2101337    11838413      -34281    13905469           0           0           0       76000           0       76000           0     2492174     1960602      531572           0       44821       16081       28740           0       87123       48395       38728           0      235735      181956       53779           0           0       30355           0       30355           0        1575           0        1575           0      234343      165594       68749           0       13115           0       13115           0        9575           0        9575           0      161423           0      161423           0       53876       22954       30922           0           0           0           0           0        4942        3913        1029           0        6149           0        6149           0        2736           0        2736           0      210362      147253       63109           0      576778      406664      144580       25534     4241082     2953412     1262136       25534     1677891           0     3728572           0      507860     4953660      892988     4984972           0           0           0           0           0       35580           0           0           0           0     3094010     4050070    14225289    18519140      546822           0           0           0       16779     4050070     2601876     4613671    11623413    13905469    18519140           0     2374909     4114739           0           0     3613146    13779702           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0     5988055    17894441     2374909     4114739       59881C    585  2204  3.7731 31 06-DEC-88861788050201

    COMMUNITY INTERFAITH, INC.         356061414174900020070283398709IN4620503NY5080NNY35606141411N      127893           0           0      127893      604477           0       23556           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0      755926      739057       31793           0           0      770850      -14924       66165      209155      260396           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0      213077      213077           0           0       59709       59709           0           0      498064      466271       31793           0      770850      739057       31793           0      604477           0      604477           0      167524           0       15960           0           0           0       36297       42899      116805        5939       80000       50500           0           0     2010730      288309     2543882     2692064       47112           0           0           0     2279539      105017     2477717     2431668       66165      260396     2692064           0       58038       75124           0           0      567197     3637593       11452       48496           0           0           0           0           0           0        2590        6268      639277     3767481       72080      129888        6393C    557  3556  6.3840    06-DEC-88861788030201

    HARPER-GRACE HOSPITALS             237321231174900023840083598612MI4820103NN    YNY23732123107N     2881438      112819           0     2994257   207954826        2395     2036913     6312598     2777760     2279162      498598           0    62652366    59537158     3115208      261070      360092      -99022     3016186       34142       32665        1477    53552506    14195646    39356860     3470983   265645093   160446101    96961567           0           0   257407668     8237425   145605070     -995921   152846574     3000000           0           0      665258      197582      467676           0   123744591    90952275    32792316           0           0           0           0           0    13635510    10294810     3340700           0     9255248     6867394     2387854           0           0      137118           0      137118           0      285626       11996      273630           0    24915176    21725932     3189244           0     3085688       77142     3008546           0      340700           0      340700           0    10231200     2414563     7816637           0     5185990     1913630     3272360           0      171132       28408      142724           0      533282      301304      231978           0      222358      109623      112735           0     8187264           0     8187264           0    14570894     4516977    10053917           0    39240633    18034465    21206168           0   257407668   160446101    96961567           0           0           0   207954826     3470983     1750129    19222592    38180683     9648547           0           0     4792358     3007118     2342637     7805578    59615768    48156649     9969252      367971   137937683    45518226   298716333   325692305    33670729     3000000     9680225           0    85620906    40873871   153111263   172845731   145605070   152846574   325692305           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0C    973   973  1.0041    06-DEC-88861788040204

    MOUNTIAN CHRISTIAN ACADEMY, INC.   311072335174900020091783198706KY4164903NN    NNN31107233506Y      255261      198318           0      453579           0           0           0           0        3706           0        3706           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0       60687       44386       16301           0      473586      490131           0           0           0      490131      -16545     1292352    -1239409       36398           0           0           0           0           0           0           0      307346      307346           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0       21975       21975           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0       46348       46348           0           0       20563       20563           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0       12906       12906           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0        6754        6754           0           0       12244       12244           0           0       61991       61991           0           0      490131      490131           0           0           0           0           0           0         755           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0      326052           0     1366644      326808      223147           0           0           0       67262           0       74292      290410     1292352       36398      326808           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0C    547 30053 54.9440    06-DEC-88861788030202

    INDIANA HISTORICAL SOCIETY         350876384174900023810183498709IN4620203NY    NNN35087638411N      230271           0      250542      480813       32112       96162           0     2404792           0           0           0           0           0           0           0    19293732    15995785     3297947     3297947           0       84010      -84010       39052      271432     -232380       10720     6006156     1794200      572224           0           0     2366424     3639732    34752568           0    38392300       42625           0           0           0           0           0           0      999788      799973      199815           0       99809       65974       33835           0       95222       78572       16650           0       71332       57490       13842           0           0        8750           0        8750           0        4280           0        4280           0       24762       13982       10780           0       11819           0       11819           0       33158           0       33158           0      230142      157191       72951           0       29245       26788        2457           0           0           0           0           0       25624       20039        5585           0       14804       14804           0           0           0           0           0           0       47834           0       47834           0      627230      516762      110468           0     2366424     1794200      572224           0           0           0       32112       10720      153671           0           0           0       11202           0           0      106000       90000        2260    27856267    31343815           0           0      485194     6546654    35011398    38632796      240496           0           0           0           0           0      258830      240496    34752568    38392300    38632796           0      225094      653359       93540      364279       95542      371697     2282400     7472554           0           0           0           0      250542     1026314        2184        7111     2949302     9895314     2853760     9523617       29493C    585  2204  3.7716    06-DEC-88861788040201
```

Comment: It sounds like there's a specific problem with line 91 in path/f990.86.raw. Does that line look different than the others? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Thanks! I added additional info. Indeed it seems to be something about line 91 but I do not see anything particular about it.